# Subclassing UIview issues

Tags: swift, uiview

I have a UIView at my view controller. And I want to draw some labels programmatically at the screen. So I thought I can subclass it and at that class to the UIView.

My code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class MainBottomView : UIView{

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds);

        generateLabel(CGRect(x: 5, y: 363, width: 310, height: 62),tekst: "")
        return;
    }

    func generateLabel(_ fr: CGRect,tekst: String){

        let l = UILabel(frame: fr)
        l.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: (21/255.0),green: (185/255.0),blue:(201/255.0),alpha:1)
        l.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        l.text = tekst
        l.textColor = UIColor.white
        l.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 23)
        self.addSubview(l)
    }
}
```

But it crashes at the required init? row. I don't know why this is happening. Or did I use subclassing at the wrong way?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your UIView comes from the storyboard / nib, it is `init?(coder:)` that *is* the initializer. So that is where your code needs to go.

Your `init`, in fact, would probably never run. The two designated initializers for UIView are `init(frame:)` (for a UIView created in code) and `init(coder:)` (for a view created from the storyboard). Those are the ones you need to override.

Comment: I have created a view at my view controller, I gave that view the class MainBottomView. So I need to replace init() with init(coder:)?

Comment: I think that's what I said, isn't it? Just take the `fatalError` out and put your call to `generateLabel` in (and call `super` of course).

Comment: I have implement it a bit different, I thought it is better this way (see my post). But it isn't working yet.

Answer (score 1):

You could play around with the code below to get the idea (Xcode 8.1 (8B62)) Delete storyboard, launchscreen, Clean properties Main story board and Launchscreen in Info.plist and replace AppDelegate.swift with the following content

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        self.window!.rootViewController = ViewController()
        self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.addSubview(MainBottomView())
    }
}

class MainBottomView : UIView{
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {super.init(coder: coder)}
    init() {
        super.init(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds);
        generateLabel(CGRect(x: 5, y: 363, width: 310, height: 62),tekst: "test")
    }

    func generateLabel(_ fr: CGRect,tekst: String){

        let l = UILabel(frame: fr)
        l.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: (21/255.0),green: (185/255.0),blue:(201/255.0),alpha:1)
        l.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        l.text = tekst
        l.textColor = UIColor.white
        l.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 23)
        self.addSubview(l)
    }
}
```